# Error inserting null or empty value in DATE column mapped to LocalDate type in java

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using MS SQL as my DB and I have a DATE column called 'START_DATE' in one of my tables. This is a non mandatory column.

In my java layer I am have mapped this to the LocalDate . When I dont have any value set for START_DATE, then I set it to null or leave it empty.

In both cases I get the error that

**Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to date is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**

How do I fix this, please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using 2012 version or newer? The problem is in the way SQL 2012 interprets null values for a datetime time. Insert query from Java should have an explicit convert function to forcefully insert it as datetime to avoid this unexpected error. 
Something like:
    convert(DATETIME,START_DATE,21)

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using sql server version 13.0 , so does that mean what you have suggested does not apply to this version and there is a different issue?

Comment: On contrary - version 13 is actually version 2016, so add explicit conversion and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SQL Server.  I fixed it by changing the insert value from just `myValue` to
`CONVERT(DATE, myValue)`